# pass SQL query in POST request using Flask

Tags: mysql, api, rest, flask, post

I want to pass a SQL query as parameter in a POST request. Ideally this SQL query will be further passed into MySQL connection, and then it can fetch data back.

Here is what I did:

These are basic modules and settings:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
from app import app
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'hibernate1'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
mysql.init_app(app)
```

This is the main.py, where I want to pass a SQL query:

```
from urllib import response
import pymysql
from app import app
from config import mysql
from flask import jsonify
from flask import flash, request

@app.route('/SQL/<query>', methods=['POST']) 
def return_query(query):
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute(query)
    Rows = cursor.fetchall()
    respone = jsonify(Rows)
    return respone

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This is test.py:

```
import requests
dictToSend = {"query": "select * from student"}
res = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/SQL', json = dictToSend)
print ('response from server:', res.text)
dictFromServer = res.json()
print(dictFromServer)
```

However, I got the following errors:

```
response from server: <!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

It says the requested URL was not found. But the following GET request works fine:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def return_hello():
    return {"data": "hello"}
```

Could anyone tell me what I missed in the POST request? Thanks.